# Spark failed due to Cassandra failure during read query at consistency LOCAL_ONE (1 responses were required but only 0 replica responded, 1 failed)

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra

I have a cluster of 6 nodes workloded with cassandra and spak.

When I run on cqlsh the query:

```
select document_id, source_name from document_spark.documents;
```

it's working properly.

But when I run the following command on spark shell:

```
scala> sc.cassandraTable("document_spark", "documents").select("document_id", "source_name").count
```

I got this exception:

```
ERROR 2016-10-04 21:15:13,602 org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSetManager: Task 2 in stage 1.0 failed 4 times; aborting job
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 2 in stage 1.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 2.3 in stage 1.0 (TID 29, 192.168.1.169): java.io.IOException: Exception during execution of SELECT "document_id", "source_name" FROM "document_spark"."documents" WHERE token("document_id") <= ?   ALLOW FILTERING: Cassandra failure during read query at consistency LOCAL_ONE (1 responses were required but only 0 replica responded, 1 failed)
        at com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.CassandraTableScanRDD.com$datastax$spark$connector$rdd$CassandraTableScanRDD$$fetchTokenRange(CassandraTableScanRDD.scala:320)
        at com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.CassandraTableScanRDD$$anonfun$18.apply(CassandraTableScanRDD.scala:334)
        at com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.CassandraTableScanRDD$$anonfun$18.apply(CassandraTableScanRDD.scala:334)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$13.hasNext(Iterator.scala:371)
        at com.datastax.spark.connector.util.CountingIterator.hasNext(CountingIterator.scala:12)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.getIteratorSize(Utils.scala:1631)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$count$1.apply(RDD.scala:1157)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$count$1.apply(RDD.scala:1157)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1858)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1858)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:66)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:89)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:227)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.ReadFailureException: Cassandra failure during read query at consistency LOCAL_ONE (1 responses were required but only 0 replica responded, 1 failed)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.ReadFailureException.copy(ReadFailureException.java:85)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.ReadFailureException.copy(ReadFailureException.java:27)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.DriverThrowables.propagateCause(DriverThrowables.java:37)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.DefaultResultSetFuture.getUninterruptibly(DefaultResultSetFuture.java:245)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.AbstractSession.execute(AbstractSession.java:64)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor21.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.SessionProxy.invoke(SessionProxy.scala:33)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy9.execute(Unknown Source)
        at com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.CassandraTableScanRDD.com$datastax$spark$connector$rdd$CassandraTableScanRDD$$fetchTokenRange(CassandraTableScanRDD.scala:309)
        ... 15 more
Caused by: com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.ReadFailureException: Cassandra failure during read query at consistency LOCAL_ONE (1 responses were required but only 0 replica responded, 1 failed)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.ReadFailureException.copy(ReadFailureException.java:95)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.Responses$Error.asException(Responses.java:128)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.DefaultResultSetFuture.onSet(DefaultResultSetFuture.java:179)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.RequestHandler.setFinalResult(RequestHandler.java:173)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.RequestHandler.access$2500(RequestHandler.java:43)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.RequestHandler$SpeculativeExecution.setFinalResult(RequestHandler.java:788)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.RequestHandler$SpeculativeExecution.onSet(RequestHandler.java:607)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.Connection$Dispatcher.channelRead0(Connection.java:1012)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.Connection$Dispatcher.channelRead0(Connection.java:935)
        at io.netty.channel.SimpleChannelInboundHandler.channelRead(SimpleChannelInboundHandler.java:105)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:307)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:293)
        at io.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateHandler.channelRead(IdleStateHandler.java:266)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:307)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:293)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:103)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:307)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:293)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:276)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:263)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:307)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:293)
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:840)
        at io.netty.channel.epoll.AbstractEpollStreamChannel$EpollStreamUnsafe.epollInReady(AbstractEpollStreamChannel.java:830)
        at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.processReady(EpollEventLoop.java:348)
        at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.run(EpollEventLoop.java:264)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:112)
        ... 1 more
Caused by: com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.ReadFailureException: Cassandra failure during read query at consistency LOCAL_ONE (1 responses were required but only 0 replica responded, 1 failed)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.Responses$Error$1.decode(Responses.java:76)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.Responses$Error$1.decode(Responses.java:37)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.Message$ProtocolDecoder.decode(Message.java:277)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.Message$ProtocolDecoder.decode(Message.java:257)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:89)
        ... 12 more

Driver stacktrace:
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1431)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1419)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1418)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1418)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:799)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:799)
        at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:236)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:799)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1640)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1599)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1588)
        at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:620)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1832)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1845)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1858)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1929)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.count(RDD.scala:1157)
        at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:61)
        at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:66)
        at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:68)
        at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:70)
        at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:72)
        at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:74)
        at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:76)
        at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:78)
        at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:80)
        at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:82)
        at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:84)
        at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:86)
        at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:88)
        at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:90)
        at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:92)
        at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:94)
        at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:96)
        at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:98)
        at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:100)
        at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:102)
        at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:104)
        at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:106)
        at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:108)
        at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:110)
        at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:112)
        at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:114)
        at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:116)
        at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:118)
        at $iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:120)
        at $iwC.<init>(<console>:122)
        at <init>(<console>:124)
        at .<init>(<console>:128)
        at .<clinit>(<console>)
        at .<init>(<console>:7)
        at .<clinit>(<console>)
        at $print(<console>)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$ReadEvalPrint.call(SparkIMain.scala:1065)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$Request.loadAndRun(SparkIMain.scala:1346)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.loadAndRunReq$1(SparkIMain.scala:840)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.interpret(SparkIMain.scala:871)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.interpret(SparkIMain.scala:819)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.reallyInterpret$1(SparkILoop.scala:857)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.interpretStartingWith(SparkILoop.scala:902)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.command(SparkILoop.scala:814)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.processLine$1(SparkILoop.scala:657)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.innerLoop$1(SparkILoop.scala:665)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$loop(SparkILoop.scala:670)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process$1.apply$mcZ$sp(SparkILoop.scala:997)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:945)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:945)
        at scala.tools.nsc.util.ScalaClassLoader$.savingContextLoader(ScalaClassLoader.scala:135)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process(SparkILoop.scala:945)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.process(SparkILoop.scala:1059)
        at com.datastax.bdp.spark.SparkReplMain$.main(SparkReplMain.scala:16)
        at com.datastax.bdp.spark.SparkReplMain.main(SparkReplMain.scala)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:731)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:181)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:206)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:121)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.DseSparkSubmitBootstrapper$.main(DseSparkSubmitBootstrapper.scala:48)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.DseSparkSubmitBootstrapper.main(DseSparkSubmitBootstrapper.scala)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Exception during execution of SELECT "document_id", "source_name" FROM "document_spark"."documents" WHERE token("document_id") <= ?   ALLOW FILTERING: Cassandra failure during read query at consistency LOCAL_ONE (1 responses were required but only 0 replica responded, 1 failed)
        at com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.CassandraTableScanRDD.com$datastax$spark$connector$rdd$CassandraTableScanRDD$$fetchTokenRange(CassandraTableScanRDD.scala:320)
        at com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.CassandraTableScanRDD$$anonfun$18.apply(CassandraTableScanRDD.scala:334)
        at com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.CassandraTableScanRDD$$anonfun$18.apply(CassandraTableScanRDD.scala:334)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$13.hasNext(Iterator.scala:371)
        at com.datastax.spark.connector.util.CountingIterator.hasNext(CountingIterator.scala:12)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.getIteratorSize(Utils.scala:1631)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$count$1.apply(RDD.scala:1157)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$count$1.apply(RDD.scala:1157)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1858)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1858)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:66)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:89)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:227)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.ReadFailureException: Cassandra failure during read query at consistency LOCAL_ONE (1 responses were required but only 0 replica responded, 1 failed)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.ReadFailureException.copy(ReadFailureException.java:85)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.ReadFailureException.copy(ReadFailureException.java:27)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.DriverThrowables.propagateCause(DriverThrowables.java:37)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.DefaultResultSetFuture.getUninterruptibly(DefaultResultSetFuture.java:245)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.AbstractSession.execute(AbstractSession.java:64)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor21.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.SessionProxy.invoke(SessionProxy.scala:33)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy9.execute(Unknown Source)
        at com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.CassandraTableScanRDD.com$datastax$spark$connector$rdd$CassandraTableScanRDD$$fetchTokenRange(CassandraTableScanRDD.scala:309)
        ... 15 more
Caused by: com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.ReadFailureException: Cassandra failure during read query at consistency LOCAL_ONE (1 responses were required but only 0 replica responded, 1 failed)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.ReadFailureException.copy(ReadFailureException.java:95)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.Responses$Error.asException(Responses.java:128)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.DefaultResultSetFuture.onSet(DefaultResultSetFuture.java:179)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.RequestHandler.setFinalResult(RequestHandler.java:173)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.RequestHandler.access$2500(RequestHandler.java:43)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.RequestHandler$SpeculativeExecution.setFinalResult(RequestHandler.java:788)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.RequestHandler$SpeculativeExecution.onSet(RequestHandler.java:607)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.Connection$Dispatcher.channelRead0(Connection.java:1012)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.Connection$Dispatcher.channelRead0(Connection.java:935)
        at io.netty.channel.SimpleChannelInboundHandler.channelRead(SimpleChannelInboundHandler.java:105)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:307)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:293)
        at io.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateHandler.channelRead(IdleStateHandler.java:266)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:307)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:293)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:103)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:307)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:293)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:276)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:263)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:307)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:293)
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:840)
        at io.netty.channel.epoll.AbstractEpollStreamChannel$EpollStreamUnsafe.epollInReady(AbstractEpollStreamChannel.java:830)
        at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.processReady(EpollEventLoop.java:348)
        at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.run(EpollEventLoop.java:264)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:112)
        ... 1 more
Caused by: com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.ReadFailureException: Cassandra failure during read query at consistency LOCAL_ONE (1 responses were required but only 0 replica responded, 1 failed)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.Responses$Error$1.decode(Responses.java:76)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.Responses$Error$1.decode(Responses.java:37)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.Message$ProtocolDecoder.decode(Message.java:277)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.Message$ProtocolDecoder.decode(Message.java:257)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:89)
        ... 12 more
```

I'm using spark 1.6.2, scala 2.10.5 and datastax 5.0

Comment: What is the definition of your Keyspace `document_spark`?

Comment: {
  "class" : "org.apache.cassandra.locator.NetworkTopologyStrategy",
  "dca" : "3"
}

Comment: Did you get any solution for this?

Comment: @wittyameta would you review the log of the cassandra nodes to check if there are corrupted files?